# How to translate a Drupal Bean programmatically?

Tags: drupal-7

I've looked everywhere, but I can't find a way to translate a bean. They rely on entity_translation, but this doesn't seem to work:

```
$form_state['build_info']['args'] = array (  0 => $bean );
$form_state['form_id'] = 'bean_form';
$form_state['entity_translation'] = array(
    'form_langcode' => $newLangcode,
    'source_langcode' => 'en',
    'is_translation' => 1,
);

drupal_form_submit('bean_form', $form_state);
```

It doesn't do anything. Any ideas what I could be missing? Or is there perhaps a better way than trying to submit the form?

My attempt is basically just an attempt at trying to mimmick what happens on this page:

```
/block/MY_BLOCK/edit/add/en/es
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me forever to find this:

```
$translation = array(
    'translate' => 0,
    'status' => 1,
    'language' => $langCode, // here is the language you're translating to
    'source' => 'en', 
);
$bean = bean_load($bid); 
$handler = entity_translation_get_handler('bean', $bean);
$values = array (
    // i add the default values here, but you can add whatever you want
);

$handler->setTranslation($translation, $values);
bean_save($bean);
```